# NodeJS not updating MySQL connection when master-slave failover happens

Tags: node.js, dns, mysql-connector

I have a MySQL cluster running with a master and a couple of slaves. I use a url which points to the master node to connect in my NodeJS application (using the mysql NodeJS package).If for some reason , my master node goes down other node is promoted as slave and master is restarted in read only mode. The url is now pointing to the new master , but my NodeJS application does not connect to the new master until it is restarted. It keeps running write queries on the old master resulting in Read only errors.

I have looked this up and Google search suggests it is caused by DNS caching but I am not sure if this is true and even if it is how I will resolve this.

I have tried searching this problem but couldn't find much. Found a similiar issue in Java application and the solution was to decrease the networkaddres.cache.ttl value but this does not apply in my case

Comment: You need to call `connect()` to perform a DNS lookup to get the new IP. Existing connections won't automatically switch.

Comment: So do I need to monitor the DNS for changes and if it changes then call connect?

Comment: Or you could use an error handler that reconnects when the connection fails.

Comment: Sadly only reconnects can fix that as @Barmar said.  If you used some kind of proxy, then that proxy could handle that totally transparent to the app